# use parse-server cloud code to do facebook authentication

Tags: javascript, graphql, parse-server, apollo

I have integrated Apollo GraphQL with parse-server using cloud code. I would now like to expose authentication mutation (within the cloud code) which will accept facebook `authData` and authenticate the user so it can return `sessionToken` as a result.

The GraphQL is secondary here - it is just a context to explain why I need to do all this in cloud code (also I am using parse-server hosting provider and using cloud code is the only reasonable way to have the GraphQL working).

to show more details here is how the integration is done
https://github.com/ciekawy/parse-server-back4app-graphql-boilerplate

and to not put just a link, `app.js` in the `cloud` folder looks like

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var apollo_server_express = require("apollo-server-express");
var graphql_tools = require("graphql-tools");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");
var resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello() { return "Hello world!"; }
    }
};

var schema = graphql_tools.makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './graphql/schema.graphql'), 'utf8'),
    resolvers: resolvers
});

app.use('/graphql', cors(), bodyParser.json(), apollo_server_express.graphqlExpress({ schema: schema }));
app.use('/graphiql', apollo_server_express.graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql'
}));
```

and so to the `resolvers` I'd like to add

```
Mutation: {
  authenticate(obj, args, context) {
     // here call some parse-server link with
  } 
}
```

I tried to use `linkWith` in different ways but with no success.

UPDATE: according to discussions on [parse-server's github](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4103) what I am trying to do may not be even supported. With better understanding of the internals I could open a ticket there.

Two possible workarounds I see (though I would not be happy with them)

1. just use REST for oauth signup/login (main drawback here is inability to provide atomic account initialization - i.e. create extra user data structures, the other is to not be able to migrate fully to GraphQL)
2. do the loopback REST call from cloud code GraphQL mutation to self

Comment: Are you facing any message error in your side? Something related to Unauthorized or empty result?

Comment: depdending on the approach used I got i.e.: `ParseError {
  code: 252,
  message: 'This authentication method is unsupported.' }`, 

The closest one was `user already exists` - yet still it is possible that the error was raised before trying to verify FB token.

Comment: Which Parse server version are you using?

Comment: currently its 2.7.4. latest available for me is 2.8.4 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: as for GraphQL in particular - parse-server since v3.6.0 introduced native GraphQL support for all parse-server API. Which means there is [GraphQL auth mutation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/graphql/guide/#logging-in) out of the box. Also since v3.7.2 it offers also support for custom schema mapped to cloud code/cloud functions.

Below workaround solution is still valid for generic cloud code.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As for now I ended up with doing internal http call from the cloud code to self - here it is if anyone would like to proceed in same situation.

```
async function authenticateWithFacebook({userProfile, ...authData}) {
    try {
        const response: HttpResponse = (await httpRequest({
            url: 'https://local-parse-server/users/',
            body: authData,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', // without this line return error is about missing user or password
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': APPLICATION_ID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': REST_API_KEY,
                'X-Parse-Revocable-Session': 1
            }
        }));
        const { data: { sessionToken }} = response;
        // here we can also do Parse.User.become(sessionToken)
        return sessionToken;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('error during authentication', e);
    }
}
```

Sill would welcome solution without loopback http call.